# Inno Setup: Confirm task (overwrite registry entry after user confirmation)

Tags: inno-setup

Currently I have a checkbox on the default options page that causes a set of registry keys to be created if they do not exist yet:

```
[Tasks]
...
Name: myUrlHandler; Description: "Register myurl://"; GroupDescription: "Advanced Options:"

[Registry]
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "myurl"; Flags: createvalueifdoesntexist uninsdeletekeyifempty; Tasks: myUrlHandler
...
```

Now I want to show a confirmation dialog in case these registry keys already exist, whether the user wants to overwrite them.

In what method I should show the confirmation dialog (that should be hideable for silent installations) and how to access this option (without adding an own page)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`NextButtonClick` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=NextButtonClick) and [`Check` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck).

```pascal
[Tasks]
Name: myUrlHandler; Description: "Register myurl"

[Registry]
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "myurl"; Check: CreateMyurlKeyCheck

[Code]

var
  CreateMyurlKey: Boolean;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectTasks then
  begin
    CreateMyurlKey := False;

    if IsTaskSelected('myUrlHandler') then
    begin
      Log('myUrlHandler task selected');

      if RegKeyExists(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, 'myurl') then
      begin
        Log('myurl key exists');

        if MsgBox('Overwrite key?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = IDYES then
        begin
          CreateMyurlKey := True;
        end;
      end
        else
      begin
        Log('myurl key does not exist');
        CreateMyurlKey := True;
      end;
    end
      else
    begin
      Log('myUrlHandler task not selected');
    end;
  end;

  Result := True;
end;

function CreateMyurlKeyCheck: Boolean;
begin
  Result := CreateMyurlKey;
end;
```